# Change attribute of an object in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In the following `df`:

```py
import pandas as pd
class Aclass:
    def __init__(self, i: int=0):
        self.name = 'A'+str(i)
        self.val = 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

one = Aclass(1)
two = Aclass(2)
three = Aclass(3)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [one, two, three], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
```

... how can the value of objects in column `a` be changed to the ints in `b` such that:

`print([i.a.val for i in df.itertuples()])`

shows `[4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: Are you trying to do this `print([(i.a.val)*(i.b) for i in df.itertuples()])` ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it is as simple as:

```py
for i in df.itertuples():
    i.a.val = i.b
```

For some reason list comprehension `[i.a.val = i.b for i in df.itertuples()]` did not work, which bummed me out!